# Are references to websites okay where one can read comics online?

Tags: discussion

Today I read the latest 6 issues of the Injustice 2 Comic. I wondered about a character and found my question [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175196/who-is-the-evil-batman-in-injustice-2) in an instant (it was closed as future-work question). By chance, this question was also answered within these issues, so I flagged the question to be reopened and I could answer.

However, someone else was faster and the manner in which he answered irritated me. In his [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175196/who-is-the-evil-batman-in-injustice-2), he linked to the exact comic site with the answer, on a site where you can read (any newer) comic online. Since I'm new here, I don't know the policies about this, but to my knowledge, sites like these are semi-illegal, so I wouldn't expect direct references like this. Is this behavior okay on this site? Especially when there are also reviews like [this](http://www.fandompost.com/2018/02/22/injustice-2-46-review/) online?

Comment: Dupe of [Should We Allow Links to Sources of a Questionable Legal Status?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1352/20774). In short, it's not our job to police the internet. I have, however, removed the link while we discuss it.

Comment: @Valorum Since it's a dupe, I flagged it myself, the comment is generated automatically o_o The question is really answered there, so there is no point for this question, except that it is a more specific formulation and may prevent that similar questions arise in the future. So this one should be closed.